# RegEx in bash-script (for-loop)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I want to parse the arguments given to a shell script by using a for-loop. Now, assuming I have 3 arguments, something like
`for i in $1 $2 $3`
should do the job, but I cannot predict the number of arguments, so I wanted use an RegEx for the range and $# as the number of the last argument. I don't know how to use these RegEx' in a for-loop, I tried something like
`for i in $[1-$#]`
which doesn't work. The loop only runs 1 time and 1-$# is being calculated, not used as a RegEx.

Answer (score 7):

### Basic

A `for` loop by default will loop over the command-line arguments if you don't specify the `in` clause:

```
for arg; do
    echo "$arg"
done
```

If you want to be explicit you can get all of the arguments as `"$@"`. The above loop is equivalent to:

```
for arg in "$@"; do
    echo "$arg"
done
```

From the bash man page:

> #### Special Parameters
>
> `$@` — Expands  to  the  positional  parameters, starting from one.  When the expansion occurs within
>                 double quotes, each parameter expands to a separate word.  That is, `"$@"` is equivalent to `"$1" "$2" ...`.   If  the  double-quoted  expansion occurs within a word, the expansion of the first
>                 parameter is joined with the beginning part of the original word, and  the  expansion  of  the
>                 last  parameter  is  joined  with the last part of the original word.  When there are no positional parameters, `"$@"` and `$@` expand to nothing (i.e., they are removed).

### Advanced

For heavy-duty argument processing, `getopt` + `shift` is the way to go. `getopt` will pre-process the command-line to give the user some flexibility in how arguments are specified. For example, it will expand `-xzf` into `-x -z -f`. It adds a `--` argument after all the flags which separates flags from file names; this lets you do run `cat -- -my-file` to display the contents of `-my-file` without barfing on the leading dash.

Try this boilerplate code on for size:

```
#!/bin/bash

eval set -- "$(getopt -o a:bch -l alpha:,bravo,charlie,help -n "$0" -- "$@")"

while [[ $1 != -- ]]; do
    case "$1" in
      -a|--alpha)
        echo "--alpha $2"
        shift 2
        ;;

      -b|--bravo)
        echo "--bravo"
        shift
        ;;

      -c|--charlie)
        echo "--charlie"
        shift
        ;;

      -h|--help)
        echo "Usage: $0 [-a ARG] [-b] [-c]" >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac
done
shift
```

Notice that each option has a short a long equivalent, e.g. `-a` and `--alpha`. The `-a` flag takes an argument so it's specified as `a:` and `alpha:` in the `getopt` call, and has a `shift 2` at the end of its case.

Comment: The Bash builtin `getopts` [is preferable](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035) to the external `getopt` since the latter "can't handle empty arguments strings, or arguments with embedded whitespace."

Comment: @Dennis That's not true nowadays. See `man getopt` to see if you have the newer enhanced version that plugs these holes: "Traditional implementations of getopt(1) are unable to cope with  whitespace  and  other  (shell-specific)  special characters in arguments and non-option parameters. To solve this problem, this implementation can generate quoted output which must once again be interpreted by the  shell..."

Comment: If backwards compatibility is important you can use the `-T` flag to test if your `getopt` is enhanced. It will return exit status 4 if it is; older `getopt`s will exit with 0.

Comment: @John: Thanks for that information. I hadn't noticed that in the man page.

Comment: @Dennis I was quite confused the first time I read that FAQ entry. The language couldn't be any stronger: **"Never use getopt(1)."** In bold. "Please forget that it ever existed." It would be really nice if the FAQ qualified that advice with *unless you have GNU's `getopt`, which is perfectly fine!*

Answer (score 1):

Another way to iterate over the arguments which is closer to what you were working toward would be something like:

```
for ((i=1; i<=$#; i++))
do
    echo "${@:i:1}"
done
```

but the `for arg` syntax that John Kugelman showed is by far preferable. There are, however, times when array slicing is useful. Also, in this version, as in John's, the argument array is left intact. Using `shift` discards its elements.

You should note that what you were trying to do with square brackets is not a regular expression at all.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest doing something else instead:

```
while [ -n "$1" ] ; do
  # Do something with $1
  shift
  # Now whatever was in $2 is now in $1
done
```

The `shift` keyword moves the content of $2 into $1, $3 into $2, etc. pp.

Let's say the arguments where:

```
a b c d
```

After a `shift`, the arguments are now:

```
b c d
```

With the while loop, you can thus parse an arbitrary number of arguments and can even do things like:

```
while [ -n "$1" ] ; do
  if [ "$1" = "-f" ] ; then
    shift
    if [ -n "$1" ] ; then
      myfile="$1"
    else
      echo "-f needs an additional argument"
    end
  fi
  shift
done
```

Imagine the arguments as being an array and $n being indexes into that array. `shift` removes the first element, so the index 1 now references the element that was at index 2 prior to `shift`. I hope you understand what I want to say.

Comment: That's a hard way of writing a simple `for` loop which does the job cleanly - no need to use shift, for example.

Comment: I see, this should be a way better approach to parse arguments in general. Thanks, I'll use it when I have a few more arguments.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Yes, the `for arg in "$@"` is easier but it's not as flexible if you're doing "serious" argument parsing... you would have to store intermediate values in temporary variables which then makes the whole job harder than with the while loop.

Comment: That while loop may terminate too early if the user actually passes an empty string argument: `a b "" d`

Comment: To avoid the problem that @glenn pointed out, you can use `while (( $#  > 0 ))` or `while [ $# -gt 0 ]`.